# Unexpected HTML output

Tags: python, html, python-2.7

I am trying generate HTML code based of an xml file input shown below,expected out is shown below,somewhere I am messing up the logic,I am getting a different output..can anyone point to what the issue is?

```
Input :-cr_fixes.xml file

<Fixes>
CR  FA  CL  Title
409452  WLAN    656885  Age out RSSI values from buffer 
409452,  12345          To Record HAL and SLM FW Event Logging
</Fixes>
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:-

```
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" border="1">
<tr>
<th bgcolor="#67B0F9" scope="col">CR</th>
<th bgcolor="#67B0F9" scope="col">FA</th>
<th bgcolor="#67B0F9" scope="col">CL</th>
<th bgcolor="#67B0F9" scope="col">Title</th>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td><a href="http://prism/CR/409452">409452</a></td>
<td>WLAN</td>
<td>656885</td>
<td>Age out RSSI values from buffer </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href=http://data/409452>409452</a>,<a href=http://data/12345>12345</a></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td>To Record HAL and SLM FW Event Logging</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

ACTUAL OUTPUT:-

```
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" border="1">
<tr>
<th bgcolor="#67B0F9" scope="col">CR</th>
<th bgcolor="#67B0F9" scope="col">FA</th>
<th bgcolor="#67B0F9" scope="col">CL</th>
<th bgcolor="#67B0F9" scope="col">Title</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="http://prism/CR/409452">409452</a></td>
<td><a href="http://prism/CR/409452">409452</a></td>
<td><a href="http://prism/CR/409452">409452</a></td>
<td><a href="http://prism/CR/409452">409452</a></td>
<td>WLAN</td>
<td>656885</td>
<td>Age out RSSI values from buffer </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td><a href="http://prism/CR/409452,  12345">409452,  12345</a></td>
 <td><a href="http://prism/CR/409452,  12345">409452,  12345</a></td>
 <td><a href="http://prism/CR/409452,  12345">409452,  12345</a></td>
 <td><a href="http://prism/CR/409452,  12345">409452,  12345</a></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td>To Record HAL and SLM FW Event Logging</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

PYTHON CODE:-

http://pastie.org/5390010

Comment: Your code has some indentation issues that you might want to consider fixing -- And this isn't a `SyntaxError`.  This is an `AttributeError`

Comment: The problem was while pasting..here it is http://pastie.org/5389908

Comment: I fixed the atribute errors and updated the code,somewhere logically I am messing up,am not getting the expected output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
TR_TEMPLATE.append('    <td>{}</td>'.format(cols[0]))
TR_TEMPLATE = '\n'.join(TR_TEMPLATE)       #<--converts TR_TEMPLATE to a string
```

In the second line, you convert `TR_TEMPLATE` from a list to a string.  On susequent iterations through the loop, you're trying to use `.append` on a string.  you probably want to move the second line out of the loop and `join` at the end.

Note that you have that same mistake at a few points in your code...

Comment: do you have any ideas on how can I fix it?

Comment: I fixed the atribute errors and updated the code,somewhere logically I am messing up,am not getting the expected output